# How to control at what edges of the Plot3D box the AxesLabels show up?

Tags: plotting, ticks, axeslabel

I am making a Plot3D for an illustration. In this case, I have to find a ViewPoint which best shows the plot peculiarities. Sometimes, after the good ViewPoint has been found the plot hides some of the AxesLabel and Ticks. The latter is not desired.

**My question**: Is there a way to control where the AxesLabels and Ticks will show up?

I mean that I use the option Boxed->True, and would like to be able to choose, at what edges of the box the AxesLabels and Ticks appear.

I understand that I can remove the AxesLabel and Ticks at all and then draw them programmatically myself, and know how to do that. This is, however, time-consuming, and I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: Are we talking about `AxesEdge`?

Comment: I think I had the same issue and noone helped: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/fixed-ticks-in-rotated-plot3d

Comment: @Syed Yes. Up to now, I did not know this option and solved the problem with its use.

Comment: No link to `AxesEdge` doc page can be found on the pages for `Boxed` or `FaceGrids` or even `Ticks`, not to mention `Plot3D`. This aspect can certainly be improved.

Comment: @Syed Yes, that's why I never saw this option in the past.

Comment: @Syed If you communicate with Wolfram Mathemetica supportm they will tell you to read the Graphics3D documentation page. Furthermore, *Plot3D* documentation page itself says: **"Plot3D has the same options as Graphics3D, with the following additions and changes:  ...."**

Comment: @user:788 If you communicate with Wolfram Mathemetica supportm they will tell you to read the Graphics3D documentation page. Furthermore, *Plot3D* documentation page itself says: **"Plot3D has the same options as Graphics3D, with the following additions and changes:  ...."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to explore the [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html) option

```
Clear["Global`*"]

opt = Join[{Automatic, None}, Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2]];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Sphere[]},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}),
  AxesEdge -> {yz, xz, xy},
  SphericalRegion -> True],
 Style["AxesEdge Option", 16],
 {{yz, Automatic, "x-axis"}, opt, ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{xz, Automatic, "y-axis"}, opt, ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{xy, Automatic, "z-axis"}, opt, ControlType -> SetterBar},
 TrackedSymbols :> {yz, xz, xy}]
```

[image]