# ParametricPlot3D locations of axes and labels

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

In 3d plots, the location of the axes are very annoying since it adjusts automatically and usually it does not appeal to what we want. I have browsed some posts but I have not seen any that dealt with this kind of issue.

Is there any option on how to manually fix the locations of the axes? In this case, I would like the $t$ axis to be on the bottom left edge. In addition, it would be great if I could also adjust the locations of the labels. You can see for example that $z$ is almost touching the coordinate $z=0.5$. A general way of doing it is better so that I could also adjust the other axes, e.g. $z$ and $x$, for later purposes.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "z"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: The answer to your first question you can find here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284384/how-to-control-at-what-edges-of-the-plot3d-box-the-axeslabels-show-up The simple workaround for the second question is to add a few white spaces in front of z: `AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "  z"}`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Indeed, `AxesEdge` is the solution which I never saw in the `Options`. The solution for the second question also worked perfectly.

Comment: From the documentation, "[`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) has the same options as [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html), with the following additions and changes:"

Comment: See `AxesOrigin`.